# UITableView not scrolling despite scrolling is enabled

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a custom subclass of UITableView with a searchbar placed in the header of the view.  My UITableView is just not scrolling.  I have looked up solutions for this issue and so far nothing has worked.  In the storyboard 'scrollling' is enabled. 'UserInteration' is also enabled. Bounces vertically is also enabled. Please can someone advise?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried `tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true`?

Comment: yes. no success

Comment: please share useful code

Comment: How many rows are there in your tableView? And pls check whether `userInteraction` is enabled for the tableView.

Comment: my results from a web service pulls down 8 records but I am only able to see 5 and a hint of the 6th record at the bottom. user interaction is enabled.

Comment: is TableView the root view or a subview?

Comment: it would be helpful if you share the code done.